# How to change placeholder of an input based on select in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to change a placeholder of an input based on select onchange method. I think there is something wrong. I can't select the option, it keep locking on Xbox Live option. Here is my code below:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="platform" @change="onChange" v-model="platform">
     <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.value">{{ option.text }}</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control" :placeholder="placeholder">
```

Here is my Vue code:

```
data() {
        return { 
            placeholder: '',
            platform: '',
            options: [
                { text: 'PSN', value: 'psn' },
                { text: 'Xbox Live', value: 'xbl' },
                { text: 'Origin', value: 'origin' }
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onChange() {
            if(this.platform = 'psn') this.placeholder = 'Enter PSN ID'
            if(this.platform = 'origin') this.placeholder = 'Enter Origin ID'
            if(this.platform = 'xbl') this.placeholder = 'Enter Xbox Live Gamertag'
        }
    }
```

So what I wanted is when I select `PSN` the placeholder changed to `Enter PSN ID` and so on.

Comment: `=` is assignment and `==` or `===` is comparison operator , you need `==` to compare  `this.platform == 'psn'` here

Comment: Agreed with @NikleshRaut's comment. Kind of unrelated to the question: the `onChange()` might need a `switch(this.platform)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However you must use `==` or `===` instead of `=`, it will be better if we use a `computed` filed here as `placeholder`

```html
<select class="form-control" id="platform" v-model="platform">
     <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.value">{{ option.text }}</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control" :placeholder="placeholder">
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    platform: '',
    options: [
      { text: 'PSN', value: 'psn', placeholder: 'Enter PSN ID' },
      { text: 'Xbox Live', value: 'xbl', placeholder: 'Enter Origin ID' },
      { text: 'Origin', value: 'origin', placeholder: 'Enter Xbox Live Gamertag' }
    ]
  }
},
computed: {
  placeholder() {
    let selected = this.options.find(o => o.value === this.platform)
    return selected ? selected.placeholder : ''
  }
}
```

In this example, `placeholder` will be produced automatically.